# Merge two multi arrays in php (using codeigniter)

Tags: php, arrays

Please, help me to merge two multi dimensional arrays. It looks like:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                )
        )
)
```

And second array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [votes] => 45
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [votes] => 9
        )

)
```

Final output that i need:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [votes] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [votes] => 2
                )
        )
)
```

I have tried array_merge, array_merge_recursive, and some tests with foreach. But anything can't help me:( Pls, help!

Comment: is both array length same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the keys are really shifted then this should work: (otherwise the -1 is not needed.)

```
<?php

foreach($array1['data'] as $key => &$subarray){
        $subarray['votes']=$array2[$key-1]->votes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in function in PHP for that but you can loop through the first array and assign values from the second manually.

```
foreach($firstArray['data'] as $key => &$value) {
    $value['votes'] = $secondArray[$key]->votes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a foreach loop on the second array? My PHP is a quite rusty but here goes:

```
foreach($arrayOne["data"] as $key => $value) {
    $sub = $arrayTwo[$key];
    $value["votes"] = $sub["votes"];
}
```

Excuse any errors, written on a mobile in a hurry to catch the bus.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP function "array_merge_recursive" http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php
and "array_values" to have indentic keys

```
$array_ret['data'] = array_merge_recursive(array_values($array1['data']), array_values($array2));
```